# How to open google chrome browser from ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

How to open google chrome browser from ionic 3 app ?
( native android google chrome ) and open link in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install plugin

```
npm install open-browser -g
```

Put this Function in your .[enter link description here][1]ts file
Set Parameters according to your requirements :::::

```
openWithSystemBrowser(url: string) {
    console.log('in system browser');

    let target = "_system";
    this.InAppBrowser.create(url, target, {
      location: 'yes',//Or 'no' 
      hidden: 'no', //Or  'yes'
      clearcache: 'yes',
      hideurlbar: 'yes',
      clearsessioncache: 'yes',
      zoom: 'yes',//Android only ,shows browser zoom controls 
      hardwareback: 'yes',
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: 'no',
      shouldPauseOnSuspend: 'no', //Android only 
      closebuttoncaption: 'Close', //iOS only
      disallowoverscroll: 'no', //iOS only 
      toolbar: 'yes', //iOS only 
      enableViewportScale: 'no', //iOS only 
      allowInlineMediaPlayback: 'no',//iOS only 
      presentationstyle: 'pagesheet',//iOS only 
      fullscreen: 'yes',//Windows only    
    });
  }
```

you can call ::::::

```
 let Path = 'https://www.google.com/';
 this.openWithInAppBrowser(path);
```

it will Open your link in Chrome
But I am having issue of using system Browser is that URL can't be hide with any of them Options...
If Required do install required Plugins according to project.